# MySQL Database Access

Tags: php, mysql

NOTE: Question Closed. I managed to figure out what was wrong.
My current code is this:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


    mysqli_select_db($con, "rbxdataa_Data");
    $Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
    $GetType=$_GET["Type"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC";
    $sql_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run)){
        echo $sql_row['EventId'].'<br>';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As I am currently very new to PHP and MySQL, I have no idea why this code will not work. I am also confused as to how I would make it echo only the top `($Amount)` as determined by how large the "EventId" value is.

My intent is to gather the `[$Amount]` highest rows in the table with the EventType `$GetType`.
I am aware of SQL Injection vulnerability, however for my purposes this does not affect me.

```
Error:
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 4"
This isn't the main error, however. I just can't read the main error yet.
```

Comment: Never share your original credentials over here http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: I recommend deleting the questions and starting over if those are legitimate connection details in the edit history.

Comment: You should change your credentials real quick

Comment: I changed them on the site... I didn't even notice, I thought I had hanged them in this post. Huge mistake on my part.

Comment: No, I mean, you should change your password on your MySQL server

Comment: Well, I recommend you change your password, because i tryed with the credentials you provided, and i have access to the `rbxdataa_Data` database (don't worry, i won't do anything )

Comment: You shouldn't, not anymore.

Comment: Your right. Good luck with the question ;-)

Comment: Looks like a PHP programming question to me.  I see PHP code, that is attempting to pull information from a database. Just adding my 2 cents to say this is in fact on topic.

Answer (score 1):

In your line 4, `mysqli_connect_error()` doesn't exist. Please check mysqli documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Edit: You may try: `printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));`

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD","rbxdataa_Data");
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC";
$sql_result = mysqli_query($con,$sql_query)
    or exit("Query fail message");
```

Otherwise looks like what I'm used to.

I just realized that no one has even asked about the $_GET variable you're using you're using.  You set $GetType from $_GET['Type'].  It could be that.

Comment: Ok, I got "Query Fail Message"... I'll check the credentials

Comment: Just to be extra safe you could try changing the corresponding part to this: ... EventType='" . $GetType . "' ORDER BY ...  Also just check to make sure the username and password in MySQL is correct, has the proper privileges to do this query.  $GetType is a string, not an integer, correct?

Comment: What are you putting in the address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }


    mysqli_select_db($con, "rbxdataa_Data");
    $Amount=$_GET["Amount"];
    $GetType=$_GET["Type"];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM EventRecord WHERE EventType='$GetType' ORDER BY EventId DESC";
    $sql_run = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($sql_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_run)){
        echo $sql_row['EventId'].'<br>';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```